# Splitting an integer to its digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to  split an integer of type `unsigned long long` to its digits.
Any comments and suggestions are always welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<unsigned short> IntegerDigits(unsigned long long input)
{
    vector<unsigned short> output;
    const unsigned short n = log10(ULLONG_MAX);
    unsigned long long divisor = pow(10, n);
    bool leadingZero = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        unsigned short digit = input / divisor % 10;
        if (!leadingZero || digit != 0)
        {
            output.push_back(digit);
            leadingZero = false;
        }
        divisor /= 10;
    }

    return output;
}

void main()
{
    vector<unsigned short> output = IntegerDigits(ULLONG_MAX);

    cout << ULLONG_MAX << ": [";
    for (auto y : output)
        cout << y << ", ";
    cout << "\b\b]";

    cout << ""<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `short n = log10(ULLONG_MAX)` will this be rounded up or down? Why?

Comment: @greybeard: Down. Because `log10(ULLONG_MAX) + 1` represents "the max number of digits" for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: What if `ULLONG_MAX` was 2⁶⁶ (2³³×2³³)?

Comment: @greybeard the max number of digits becomes 20. What is the problem?

Comment: @greybeard `n+1` represents the max number of digits.

Comment: The problem is that a rounded up `pow(10, n)` may not be "losslessly" assignable to an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I don't know why you choose to not add `#include <cmath>`. Produced `pow` not defined on my Computer, compiled with `c++14`

Comment: @theProgrammer: I don't know why. In my machine it is available without `cmath`.

Comment: Perhaps, you compiler did some underground work, but it's good practice to explicitly include necessary headers. `explicit is better than implicit`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Avoid mixing floating point and integer arithmetic

As mentioned by greybeard, there is a potential problem here:

```
const unsigned short n = log10(ULLONG_MAX);
```

`ULLONG_MAX` is larger than can be exactly represented by a `double`. This means the result might not be what you expect. The same goes for `pow(10, n)`. While you can compensate for it, it is better to find a way to calculate the length of a number without using floating point math.

## Keep it simple

Unless performance is a big concern, keep it simple. You don't have to know the number of digits up front if you push trailing digits to the front of the vector, like so:

```
vector<unsigned short> IntegerDigits(unsigned long long input)
{
    vector<unsigned short> output;

    while (input)
    {
        output.insert(output.begin(), input % 10);
        input /= 10;
    }

    // Handle input being equal to 0
    if (output.empty())
    {
        output.push_back(0);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Pushing to the front of a `std::vector` is less efficient, but on the other hand you don't need the `double`<->`int` conversions, and you don't need to handle the leading zeros inside the loop.

## Avoid using `std::endl`

[Prefer using `"\n"` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n), the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces a flush of the output, which can be bad for performance.

## Avoid backspaces in the output

You used a neat trick to get rid of the last comma without having to have extra logic inside the `for`-loop in `main()`. However, consider that the output might not just be for human consumption, but is written to a file and/or is parsed by another program. In that case, the `\b` characters are probably unexpected and might cause problems.

Comment: Where is `push_front` defined?

Comment: I changed to `stack` instead of `vector` because `push_front` has not been  defined in `vector`. :-)

Comment: Ehr oops, I meant `insert(output.begin(), ...)`!

Comment: Better to just append and then reverse in-place?

Comment: Or use a `std::deque`. The are many ways one could do this, but since it's likely only a few digits will be stored, I don't think it's going to matter much. This is where I would just keep the simplest approach, and only change it when performance becomes a bottleneck and measurements have shown that this function is a big contributor.

Comment: Why don't you take each element individually, push into a `stack`. Nice and easy.

Comment: @Deduplicator Even better: `return {std::rbegin(output), std::rend(output)};`

Comment: @Casey That would be shorter, but means one more allocation. Probably sub-optimal, though the compiler might optimise it away.

Answer (score 2):

As @G. Sliepen said, I also want to reiterate, when performance isn't a problem, ensure to make the code as simple as possible.

A modified version using `stack` might be written like this

```
void separate_digits( stack<int> &s, long long int digits )
{
    while( digits != 0 ) 
    {
        s.push( digits % 10 );
        digits /= 10;
    }
}
```

Displaying the digit would just require you to `pop` the stack, which as we know takes constant time

```
void print_separated_digits( stack<int> &s ) 
{
    while( !s.empty( ) )
    {
        std::cout << s.top( ) << " ";
        s.pop( );
    }
}
```